# Difference between .Owner property and ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner)?

Tags: c#, winforms, modal-dialog, mdi

I presume a winform's owner can be set explicitly via the **.Owner** property OR by passing the owner in the overloaded method **ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner)**

I am unable to understand why these methods exhibit different behavior when working with **MDI forms**.

I have created an MDIParent and an MDIChild.

I also have a simple winform MyDialogBox that displays its owner on load.

```
MessageBox.Show("Dialog's owner is " + this.Owner.Name);
```

Method A -  In the load of MDIChild I have the following code, which causes the MyDialogBox's owner to be set to **MDIChild**

```
MyDialogBox box = new MyDialogBox();
box.Owner = this; // Set owner as MDIChild
box.ShowDialog();
```

Method B -  Alternatively, in the load method of MDIChild I have the following code, which causes the MyDialogBox's owner to be set to **MDIParent**

```
MyDialogBox box = new MyDialogBox();
box.ShowDialog(this); // Pass MyMDIChild as owner
```

I also read the following [here](http://vbnet.mvps.org/index.html?code/forms/mdiownedwindows.htm)

*Only the MDI parent form can own another form, be it a MDI child, a modal dialog or a form where the parent was set as the Owner param.*

If so Method A should not work at all, isn't it ?

What am I missing? Why doesn't method B set the owner to MDIChild ?

Comment: Try doing this in VB6 & see whether it matches with the link you provided. If it does, I guess - framework has a bug.

Comment: Not sure about VB6 but VB.NET seems to behave the same way as C#

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the differences of these 2 options using Reflector, it seems that they have a slightly different implementation:
`box.Owner = this` just assign the provided value of this to the internal owner field.
However, when calling `ShowDialog(IWin32Window)`, the implementation performs the following call, prior to assigning the value:

```
owner = ((Control) owner).TopLevelControlInternal;
```

This might result in assignment of the MDIParent.

(**Note**: I'm far from being an expert regarding MDI, so I might be wrong here).

Comment: Interesting. Why MS would want the two to behave differently amazes me.

Comment: Yes that's really strange. I don't see why you'd want to set an owner other than the MDI parent. The idea is that when the user clicks on the MDI form, the modal dialog will be shown front most. Otherwise it would seem as if the MDI parent is locked/crashed.