# How do I set an umanaged dialog as the Owner of a WinForm Form?

Tags: c#, c++, interop, winforms-interop

I need to be able to get a WinForm dialog's Owner's HWND.  In unmanaged I have a background thread that gets the HWND for the window in front.  The code then calls ::GetParent(frontHWND) to see if it needs to hide a different non-modal MFC dialog.  When the WinForm dialog is the frontHWND, I always get NULL back for the GetParent call.  I have also tried GetOwner realizing .Net tried to cleanup the difference between Parent and Owner.  Looking at the WinForm dialog w/ Spy++, it also say the WinForm has no parent or owner.  I have passed in

```
NativeWindow ^natWin = gcnew NativeWindow();
natWin->AssignHandle(IntPtr(hwndParent));
managedDlg->ShowDialog(natWin);
```

The above code didn't set the owner of the WinForm.  I tried calling the Win32 SetParent from the WinForm code in OnFormShown(), but the locked up the MFC application and the WinForm.

Can someone explain how to get my unmanaged dialog/app to be the owner/parent of the managed winform?

Comment: Any information will be helpful... like what ShowDialog(IWin32Window) actually sets.  According to this link, [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/395186/difference-between-owner-property-and-showdialogiwin32window-owner), it should be setting the owner but when I use Spy++ I don't see that.

Answer (score 5):

To show a C# form with a C++ parent I do this:

```
void GUIWrapper(HWND parent)
{
    System::IntPtr myWindowHandle = System::IntPtr(parent);
    System::Windows::Forms::IWin32Window ^w = System::Windows::Forms::Control::FromHandle(myWindowHandle);
    ManagedDialog::ManagedDialogGUI ^d = gcnew ManagedDialog::ManagedDialogGUI();
    d->Show(w);
}
```

this code is put in a C++/CLI wrapper DLL.
Hope this helps.

**Edit:** "w" must be tested against *nullptr*, because **Control::FromHandle** could fail. See here:
[Why Control.FromHandle(IntPtr) returns null in one hooked process and returns valid object of "Form"? in another hooked process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509562/why-control-fromhandleintptr-returns-null-in-one-hooked-process-and-returns-va)

So, fail-safe code would be:

```
    if (w == nullptr)
        d->Show();
    else
        d->Show(w);
```